# How do you scroll down to navbar when a nav link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to automatically scroll down when a link in the navbar is clicked. Right now when links in the navbar are clicked the page reloads and returns to the top of the page. I used JQuery to hide the sections that aren't selected now I need to add the scroll method when a link is clicked. OR build it so that when the navbar link is selected, the page reloads with the new unhidden section, and the page moves down to the navbar. I would like to see both methods if possible.

```
 <div id="tab_container">
                    <nav id="tabs">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Our Staff</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">book</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an ID for the link to point to. If you only link to '#', the page will simply reload.

This link will jump to the corresponding ID on the H2

```
    <a href="#mylink">Click to move to ID 'myLink'</a>

    <h2 id="myLink">My link</h2>
```

As for the jQuery, did you use `.hide()`, `.toggle()` or `.remove()`?

`.hide()` [does exactly that](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), but doesn't delete it from the DOM.

`.toggle()` [switches between visible and invisible](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

`.remove()` actually [deletes your target](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) from the DOM, and it can't be manipulated after that.

Comment: Great answer! So simple, my page is beginning to look a lot more professional now,and I learned something!